# When I run PHP function to append parameter to array, it only shows the most recent parameter passed as the only element within the array

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

```
$needleArray = array();

function filter(){
  $x = $_POST['data'];
  global $needleArray;
  $filterArray = arraycompare($x, $needleArray);
  echo "<ul id='suitCat'>";
      foreach ($filterArray as $key) {
          echo $key;
      }
  echo "</ul>";
  die();
}

function arraycompare($x, $arrayParam){
  echo $arrayParam;
  array_push($arrayParam, $x);
  return $arrayParam;
}
```

So what I want to happen is to pass in a parameter into the first function filter(), which is $x and then have that append to the global array $needleArray. So every time this function is called, it just keeps appending other elements into the already existing array. However, currently when I call the function multiple times, it says the only element currently in the array is the one I most recently passed into it. I'm sure it has something to do with global scope or something but I can't figure it out.

I also have die(); in there due to the fact that this is a AJAX function running in wordpress, which requires the function to have it.

Comment: You're not actually using $needleArray.. also why are you setting it into global ?

Comment: Yes I am, Im passing the needleArray into the second function and running it through arraycompare, in which I append the $x to the $needlearray and return the result. My goal is to add on to the existing $needlearray, but it seems to add on to a empty array.

Comment: Don't use the global keyword. You declare the var before filter which means it is already available in your array comp function... But if you want to continue the way you are trying, you need to pass by reference.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

So don't return, just change the var in the function.

Comment: As in replace return $arrayParam; with what?

Comment: i would read up on the link, it should explain it all in more depth than i can on here. cheers.